# I can't find the error in my formula that's causing the #VALUE

Tags: excel, formula

My formula is

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK(F2),ISBLANK(D2)),"MISSING",F2-D2)
```

`D2` and `F2` are both dates, `F2` only has a date if something has been entered for that invoice so not all cells in column F have a date. So if the cell in column F is blank, I want the formula to put `"MISSING"` in the cell of the formula but I'm getting

> #VALUE!

Where am I going wrong with this formula?

Comment: When stuff like this happens, just use each function separately. Put each `ISBLANK` in one cell, then another with the `OR` and finally one with the `IF`. This way you can see where exactly the problem occurs. But my guess is that what's failing is `F2-D2`, maybe one of them is a text value?

Comment: Aika, still there?

Answer (score 2):

Your formula will attempt the subtraction even if the values in the cells are text.

If you want to calculate only when both cells have dates, then use IsNumber() instead of IsBlank(), but you need to change OR() to AND() and reverse the true/false actions.

```
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(F6),ISNUMBER(D6)),F6-D6,"Missing")
```

[image]

Comment: If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.